# Heroku error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask ,render_template,request,url_for,redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import psycopg2
app=Flask(__name__)



app.debug=False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgres://myherokupostgresdatabasepassword'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']=False
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class Username(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "username"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True)
    def __init__(self,username):
        self.username=username
@app.route("/submit",methods=["POST"])
def submit():
    if request.method=="POST":
        usernamee=request.form["username"]
        usernamee=usernamee.replace(" ","")
        sayi=db.session.query(Username).filter(Username.username==usernamee).count()
        print("has been created-------------------->>",sayi,"times")
        if usernamee=="" or usernamee==" ":
            return "input is empty .please enter real username."
        if sayi>0:
            return "{} didnt created .because there is username like this alreay.".format(usernamee)
        register=Username(username=usernamee)
        db.session.add(register)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("submit.html",message="{} have been entered".format(usernamee))
    return render_template("submit.html")
@app.route("/",)
def index():
    all=db.session.query(Username).all()

    return render_template("register.html",usernames=all)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

error:*

> 2020-04-19T18:51:16.120751+00:00 app[web.1]:   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>   line 127, in connect 2020-04-19T18:51:16.120751+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>   2020-04-19T18:51:16.120752+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not
>   connect to server: Connection refused 2020-04-19T18:51:16.120752+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and
>   accepting 2020-04-19T18:51:16.120752+00:00 app[web.1]:    TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

*
**when i run this command**

```
>> from app import db
>> db.create_all()
```

**it gives me this error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       return fn()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 363, in connect
>       return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 773, in _checkout
>       fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 492, in checkout
>       rec = pool._do_get()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
>   line 139, in _do_get
>       self._dec_overflow()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 69, in **exit**
>       exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 178, in raise_
>       raise exception   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
>   line 136, in _do_get
>       return self._create_connection()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 308, in _create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 437, in **init**
>       self.**connect(first_connect_check=True)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 657, in __connect
>       pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 69, in __exit**
>       exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 178, in raise_
>       raise exception   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 652, in **connect
>       connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 114, in connect
>       return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 490, in connect
>       return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init**.py",
>   line 127, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>           Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 1033, in create_all
>       self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py",
>   line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
>       op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py",
>   line 4321, in create_all
>       ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst, tables=tables   File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2057, in _run_visitor
>       with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in
>   **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2049, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
>       with self._contextual_connect() as conn:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2251, in _contextual_connect
>       self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2289, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       e, dialect, self   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1555, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
>       sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 178, in raise_
>       raise exception   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
>       return fn()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 363, in connect
>       return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 773, in _checkout
>       fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 492, in checkout
>       rec = pool._do_get()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
>   line 139, in _do_get
>       self._dec_overflow()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 69, in **exit**
>       exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 178, in raise_
>       raise exception   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py",
>   line 136, in _do_get
>       return self._create_connection()   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 308, in _create_connection
>       return _ConnectionRecord(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 437, in **init**
>       self.**connect(first_connect_check=True)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 657, in __connect
>       pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 69, in __exit**
>       exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 178, in raise_
>       raise exception   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py",
>   line 652, in **connect
>       connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py",
>   line 114, in connect
>       return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 490, in connect
>       return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init**.py",
>   line 127, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused
>           Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>
> > > >

Comment: Do you have a PostgreSQL server running on localhost?

Comment: no @ Ilja Everilä

Comment: In that case the error is pretty self explanatory: "Connection refused **Is the server running on host "localhost" ...?**" If on the other hand you meant to connect to some other host, fix your DB URI.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I think my DB URI is correct because i am using what heroku gives me

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.